# Why is my image taking up more height in the background space than the image itself?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have inserted an image into a website and now want to write a paragraph in a new div below it. I noticed that there was extra white space and colored each background of the elements pink & red to understand which was causing a problem. The pink is attributed to div of id="parent", and the red is only attributed to the id="hero_image" contained in the parent div. If it's in the parent, why is the red extending beyond the pink? I'm still trying to grasp position in CSS and what the computer "sees".

[Here is an image of what I am seeing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIWQn.jpg)

Here is my html & CSS (the nav styling is missing from CSS bc I checked and removed it to make sure it wasn't the issue)

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans HK', sans-serif;
}
 
    
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: violet;
    height: 70vw;
}


.hero-text {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    right: 10vw;
    top: 28vw;
    z-index: 9;
    font-size: 3.5vw;
    float: right;
    color: white;
}

#logo_png {
    max-width: 25vw;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}

#hero_img {
    max-width: 85vw;
    float: right;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">

            
            <h1>
                <a href='THIS WILL BE LINK TO HOME PAGE'>
                    <img id="logo_png" src="C:\Users\rebec\Desktop\LBS WEBSITE\Images\lbs_blue_circle_logo_1500x1500.png" alt="Little Big Scientists"/>
                </a>
            </h1>
            
    
            <h1>
                <img id="hero_img" src="Images/circle_hands_lbsphoto.png" alt="Little Big Scientists"/>
            </h1>

            <div class="hero-text">
                <p>We’re on a mission to teach,
                    <br>guide, and empower the next
                    <br> generation of scientists
                </p>
            </div>  

            <!-- Div for Nav Bar-->
            <div id="container"> 

                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
        
            </div>

    </div>

    <div id="test">
            <h2 class="p1">Inspiring Education</h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your style properties have wrong values !

`vh` is for height and `vw` is for width !

anyways , your `#hero_img` has `height : 85vw` which is greater than `#parent` 's height of `70vw`.

this should fix the overflow !

```
#hero_img {
    max-width: 25vh;
    float: right;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    
    background-color: tomato;
}
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: violet;
    height: 35vh;
}
```

vh and vw are relative units used to style the element according to the size of the view port !

[this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-unit-guide/) covers more about them and other units too !

Comment: I followed that and the red still extends below the photo. The photo is a circle png, so I don't understand why the red extends an inch below the photo no matter what. EVen if I make the photo really small, the red will still extend below it in the same ratio